# Incorrect button placement on emulator compared to xml graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

So, i'm trying to get four buttons in the right place, but on the emulator the buttons are all messed up. I use the same device on the emulator as on the xml layout.

XML Graphical Layout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCzXz.png

Emulator Layout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/94H3F.png

XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/mainmenu" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splay"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
    android:text="" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mplay"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="322dp"
    android:text="" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/menustat"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="389dp"
    android:text="" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/menuset"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="455dp"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why this occurs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try on a real device.. that will tell you if there is a problem with emulator.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the emulator. I guess I should have tested it there before asking questions. beginner mistake. What could be wrong with the emulator then? I use the same device as in the xml layout.

Comment: why you gave as much top margin between two button ?

Comment: You should never ever ever never!!! use one background with all button backgrounds in it. Please read the button design guidelines! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground

Comment: Because when I tried to do "android:layout_margin"123dp"" the button went to the top.

Comment: I'm very new to programming of any sort, so thank you Rolf for the tip! I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the buttons correctly.

Give the buttons the background they need and the text. Currently you're buttons are in the background of your RelativeLayout.

Comment: I want my buttons to be transparent.

Comment: @Gerfort style your buttons properly see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground

Comment: Then you have to create images which background is red but with an alpha < 100. Use that image as background for your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Single Player", "Multiplier" etc are part of your background image. And in emulator your buttons positions are not maintaining that positions due to your height & marginTop.

you should use individual background image for the button instead of a single background image.  This approach is not good at all.

Answer (score 0):

You give margin is not proper so try this way :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gerfort's"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rock,Paper &amp; Scissros"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/splay"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SingelPlayer" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mplay"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Multiplayer" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menustat"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Statistics" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuset"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not draw your buttons in backgound image, maybe you can setText in buttons. And your codes will deform in different devices.

The other way, just cut every button to image, and setBackground to your buttons.

Any way, you should remove your buttons from backgound image first!

Comment: For transparent, just use ImageView instead of Button. Set button image to ImageView's backgound, and set tranparent drawable to ImageView's src. maybe should use scaleType "fitXY".